# ayudita con INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer un inner join en una tabla con un ciclo while, estoy muy verde todavía, me gustaría alguien que explicara un poco como resolverlo en este caso, quiero que en la columna de genero no me salga el numero de ID sino el nombre.

Aquí el código:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Grupo o Artista</th>
    <th>Genero</th>
    <th>Imagen</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <?php
    $sel = $con->query("SELECT id, nombre, grupoartista, idgenero, imagen, precio FROM productos");
    while ($fila = $sel->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $fila['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['grupoartista']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['idgenero']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['imagen']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $fila['precio']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="actualizar.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id'] ?>">Editar</a></td>
            <td><a href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id'] ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Un Saludo

Comment: Tienes dos tablas? me refiero a que si tienes otra tabla donde están los géneros? Digo para hacer el **Join** de la tabla productos con la otra tabla. Y que campos tiene?, si es que existe

Comment: si, una tabla producto y otra genero y en id genero quiero mostrar el nombre no el id

Comment: si vi q hay varias sobre inner join pero es que como no entiendo bien como va, no lo entiendo lo que me han sugerido q ya esta contestado en otro post, solo quería que me ayudaran a entender como funciona.

Comment: Abre de nuevo la pregunta. podría explicarte. Tu consulta quedaría así: `SELECT productos.id, 
productos.nombre, 
productos.grupoartista, 
productos.idgenero, 
genero.nombre, 
productos.imagen, 
productos.precio 
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN genero 
ON productos.idgenero = genero.idgenero`